# My SQL Query for Search Box

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table

```
 date      | Expedition | Destination 
________________________________________
12/05/2012 |  UPS       |  New York
12/05/2012 |  DHL       |  New York
13/06/2012 |  ATLAS     |  Atlanta
14/06/2012 |  JNE       |  Chicago
```

I want to create search result and this my code

```
 <form method="post" action="sales.php?ID=expLocal">
   Pencarian <input type="text" name="KUNCI" width="300"/><input type="submit" name="CARI"        value="CARI" />
 </form>



 <?php

  if (empty($_POST[CARI]))
  {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_exp_local";//this query for open all the data
  }
   else if (isset($_POST[KUNCI]))
  {
   $kunci=$_POST[KUNCI];
   $sql="SELECT * FROM tb_exp_local WHERE MATCH (expedition,destination,date)       AGAINST ('+$kunci' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"; // this is query for serching the data
  } 

   ?>
```

The query runs well, but if the search box is filled with date the query does not run. Can anyone tell me how to correct this?(data type of column date is varchar)

Comment: why not use date data type for date column?

Comment: how do you prevent SQL injection?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar I use varchar to prepare in spesific case.

Answer (score 1):

1. $kunci=$_POST["KUNCI"];
2. carefull with Mysql match syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)
3. try to review mysql query when something is going wrong - a simple echo $sql will do so;

Answer (score 1):

Are CARI and KUNCI defined anywhere in your sales.php?

Otherwise you need to check their values using

- $_POST["CARI"]
- $_POST["KUNCI"]